# Simple CMS for use on local Mac OS computer

Tags: osx, cms

I need to create an application on a local machine within a small museum.
It displays, among other things, some information which will change from time to time.

So the client wants to be able to change certain content (text, video, images).
So now I'm looking for a small, lucid [Content Management System (CMS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management), with a configurable [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) which I could use within the local network (browser-based would be optimal).

I was looking into [Django](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_(web_framework)) / [Mezzanine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mezzanine_(CMS)?wprov=sfsi1), but maybe someone some more suggestions?

Security is not so much an issue, since the network is basically closed so there is no way for the public to access the API / CMS.

Comment: first of all you didnt specify what programming language you want, and secondly wordpress is one of the simplest, if not the simplest cms, which can do whatever you want by using plugins. And lastly, the OS is never a problem, programming languages are available for all platforms these days